# non-linear system of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of equations and aim to solve it analytically. My main problem is MATLAB code or function(s) to solve it. Any one can help me?
($$a_i, b_i, c_i$$ and $$d_i$$ are known parameters)

$$\dot x(t) =a_1-b_1x(t)y(t)-c_1x(t)z(t)-d_1x(t)$$
$$\dot y(t) = b_1x(t)y(t)+c_1x(t)z(t)-d_2y(t)$$
$$\dot z(t) =a_2y(t)-b_2z(t)$$
$$\dot u(t) =a_3y(t)-b_3u(t)$$
$$\dot s(t) =a_4u(t)-b_4s(t)$$

Comment: What does your dot represent? I'm assuming not differentiation with respect to $t$ in this case (as it usually means) but it'd be good to know. Also, some context might be helpful - are these some sort of variation on Lotka Volterra?

Comment: Dear Chris Lewis
Thanks for your valuable comments. I have corrected the equations.
These are a system of epidemic compartment model.

Comment: Thanks! One other question, you say you're looking for an analytical solution but that you're using MATLAB. Did you mean you were looking for a numerical solution?

Comment: Dear Chris Lewis Thanks again. Indeed I am looking analytical (or symbolic in terms of parameters) solution. A solution like following commands:

$$syms\ \  y(t) \ \ a $$
$$eqn = diff(y,t,2) == a*y;$$
 $$ySol(t) = dsolve(eqn).$$
Unfortunately I can't use the above for my problem!!

Comment: Initial condition can be assumed as x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0, ..., s(0)=s_0.

Comment: I don't know for sure but suspect this will be beyond MATLAB's capabilities. The way the functions are connected and the non-linearity in the first two equations seem to make this system unlikely to have an analytical solution at all. That said, you can probably get quite far with qualitative analysis and numerical solution. There's obviously a special case to consider when $d_1=d_2$ (which you can solve for $x+y$) - is this case of interest?

Comment: Also any reduction in parameters would be helpful. Just to clarify, I can't say for sure whether MATLAB will be able to handle this analytically - perhaps others can speak to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We will wait for the opinions of other respected researchers.